# Using current user in Rails in a model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently trying to implement simple audit for users (just for destroy method). This way I know if the user has been deleted by an admin or user deleted itself. I wanted to add `deleted_by_id` column to my model.

I was thinking to use `before_destroy`, and to retrieve the user info like described in this post :

http://www.zorched.net/2007/05/29/making-session-data-available-to-models-in-ruby-on-rails/

```
module UserInfo
  def current_user
    Thread.current[:user]
  end

  def self.current_user=(user)
    Thread.current[:user] = user
  end
end
```

But this article is from 2007, I'm not sure will this work in multithreaded and is there something more up to date on this topic, has anyone done something like this lately to pass on the experience?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using that technique would certainly work, but will violate the principle that wants the Model unaware of the controller state.

If you need to know who is responsible for a deletion, the correct approach is to pass such information as parameter.

Instead of using callbacks and threads (both represents unnecessary complexity in this case) simply define a new method in your model

```
class User
  def delete_user(actor)
    self.deleted_by_id = actor.id
    # do what you need to do with the record
    # such as .destroy or whatever
  end
end
```

Then in your controller simply call

```
@user.delete_user(current_user)
```

This approach:

1. respects the MVC pattern
2. can be easily tested in isolation with minimal dependencies (it's a model method)
3. expose a custom API instead of coupling your app to ActiveRecord API

Answer (score 0):

You can use [paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia) gem to make soft deletes. And then I suggest destroying users through some kind of service. Check, really basic example below:

```
class UserDestroyService
  def initialize(user, destroyer)
    @user = user
    @destroyer = destroyer
  end

  def perform
    @user.deleted_by_id = @destroyer.id
    @user.destroy
  end
end

UserDestroyService.new(user, current_user).perform
```